# Adding an option group using AWS CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, rds, aws-cloudformation

I'm building a CloudFormation template that will create a SQL Server database (using RDS) with the Multi-AZ option (so it maintains a synchronous standby replica in a different Availability Zone).

However, to make this work, I need to associated the database instance with an option group that has the Mirroring option. Haven't been able to find anywhere how to create an option group with a CloudFormation template.

How do I create an option group in a CloudFormation template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, option groups are not supported by CloudFormation. If the database needs to be created within the template, you can create the option group with the `cli` beforehand and set it as a parameter. This way you can correctly populate the `OptionGroupName` value for the `AWS::RDS::DBInstance` resource.

Answer (score 0):

Replication group is not supported feature by CloudFormation templates yet. So only possible way to create a external python script that will create the replication group with Boto lib

Example how to create Redis replication group

```
import boto.elasticache
import time
import sys

connection = boto.elasticache.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-2')

connection.create_cache_subnet_group(
    "Redis-Subnet-Group-Test", 
    "Redis cluster subnet", 
    ["subnet-72313306", "subnet-7a06e01f"]
)

connection.create_cache_cluster(
    "Redis-Master-Test", 
    num_cache_nodes = 1, 
    cache_node_type = "cache.t1.micro", 
    engine = "redis", 
    engine_version = "2.6.13", 
    cache_subnet_group_name = "Redis-Subnet-Group-Test", 
    security_group_ids = ["sg-07ff1962"],
    preferred_availability_zone = "ap-southeast-2a",
    preferred_maintenance_window = "tue:01:00-tue:02:00",
    auto_minor_version_upgrade = True
)

counter = 0
while counter < 35: # Wait for the cache cluster (redis master) to become available before creating the replication group
    counter = counter + 1
    clusterDesc = connection.describe_cache_clusters(cache_cluster_id = "Redis-Master-Test")
    clusterStatus = clusterDesc["DescribeCacheClustersResponse"]["DescribeCacheClustersResult"]["CacheClusters"][0]["CacheClusterStatus"];

    if "available" not in clusterStatus:
        time.sleep(10)

    elif "available" in clusterStatus:
        break

    else: # Just roll back on timeout
        connection.delete_cache_cluster("Redis-Master-Test")
        connection.delete_cache_subnet_group("Redis-Subnet-Group-Test")
        sys.exit(1)

connection.create_replication_group("Redis-Replicas-Test", "Redis-Master-Test", "Redis-Replication-Group")

connection.create_cache_cluster(
    "Redis-Replica-Test",
    num_cache_nodes = 1, 
    replication_group_id = "Redis-Replicas-Test",
    cache_node_type = "cache.t1.micro", 
    engine = "redis", 
    engine_version = "2.6.13", 
    cache_subnet_group_name = "Redis-Subnet-Group-Test", 
    security_group_ids = ["sg-07ff1962"],
    preferred_availability_zone = "ap-southeast-2b",
    preferred_maintenance_window = "tue:01:00-tue:02:00",
    auto_minor_version_upgrade = True
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think you're confused. My question was about option groups rather than replication groups, and I'm using RDS rather than Redis.

Comment: Sorry about confusing you...Redis was just an similar example that I faced with in my case and found that it was impossible to make via template(info was confirmed by Amazon) and I think the situation with RDS is similar, especially in case that you can't find any info how to create it via CloudFormation