# AWS Cloudformation template Oracle DB option groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to apply an Option Group when I create my Oracle RDS instance.  I am trying to set Oracle Native Network Encryption through the Option Groups.  We have already some setup but I was trying to create an Option Group on the fly and add set the settings.  I read this article here that says it is not supported.  Is that still the case?
[Article on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29725685/adding-an-option-group-using-awscloudformation)

If I can create them on the fly as the stack is being created I get an error that says a resource section is needed.  What am I missing here?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
OracleRDSOptionGroup:
  Type: AWS::RDS::OptionGroup
  Properties: 
    OptionGroupDescription: "Allows NNE"
    EngineName: oracle-ee-cdb
    MajorEngineVersion: "19"
    OptionConfigurations: 
      -
        OptionName: NATIVE_NETWORK_ENCRYPTION
        OptionSettings:
           -
             Name: SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_SERVER
             Value: "SHA1,MD5"
           - 
             Name: SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER
             Value: "REQUIRED"
           -    
             Name: SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER
             Value: "AES256"
           -
             Name: SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_SERVER
             Value: "REQUIRED"
```

Comment: I also noticed that almost your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not onlly a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances of your issues being actually answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> resource section is needed.

Well, you need [Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resources-section-structure.html) section:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
    OracleRDSOptionGroup:
    Type: AWS::RDS::OptionGroup
    Properties: 
        OptionGroupDescription: "Allows NNE"
        EngineName: oracle-ee-cdb
        MajorEngineVersion: "19"
        OptionConfigurations: 
        -
            OptionName: NATIVE_NETWORK_ENCRYPTION
            OptionSettings:
            -
                Name: SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_TYPES_SERVER
                Value: "SHA1,MD5"
            - 
                Name: SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_SERVER
                Value: "REQUIRED"
            -    
                Name: SQLNET.ENCRYPTION_TYPES_SERVER
                Value: "AES256"
            -
                Name: SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_SERVER
                Value: "REQUIRED"
```

Comment: You are correct.  I realized that I had done this before in rather CF template.  I just went back and used that code.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @cptkirkh No problem. Acceptance of the answer would be appreciated if it was useful.